# Installing ExcelPackage with Visual Studio 2008 with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, excel

I need to install the ExcelPackage library on Visual Studio 2008. The .zip file I downloaded from their website (http://excelpackage.codeplex.com) contains a .dll, a .xml file, a "GacReg.exe" and a file called ExcelPackage (with this description: "Program Debug Database"). What are the steps to installing this library, or any library in general? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

ExcelPackage.dll is a .NET assembly

ExcelPackage, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f8bb63aa9d6969e8

you can just reference it directly in your project or install it into the global assembly cache using GacReg.bat